# Implementing CrudeRepository with an interface and Long

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data

I'm trying to implement a generic crude repository but spring boot is giving a 'Not a managed type' exception - on that interface (IStorable) that I'm parameterizing my the CrudeRepository with. I would appreciate if anyone here could help me out. Thank you!

I have my repo:

```
 package com.project.biddingSoft.dao;
    public interface IRepo extends CrudRepository<IStorable, Long> {
    }
```

Then I have my interface:

```
  package com.project.biddingSoft.model;
    public interface IStorable {
        public Long getId() ;
    }
```

After that I have my entity class:

```
   package com.project.biddingSoft.model;
    @Entity
    public class Lot implements IStorable {

    @Override
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private  Long id;

    setters, getters and attributes as usual..
    
    }
```

This is the main class:

```
   package com.project.biddingSoft;
    @SpringBootApplication(exclude = {SecurityAutoConfiguration.class })
    public class BiddingSoftwareApplication implements CommandLineRunner {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            SpringApplication.run(BiddingSoftwareApplication.class, args);
            
        }
```

This is the controller (to explain my intent):

```
package com.project.biddingSoft.controller;
public class ServletInitializer extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
  
    @Autowired
    private DaoServiceImpl daoServiceImpl;
   
   configure method etc..

    @PostMapping(path = "/addent")
    ResponseEntity<Object> addNewEntity(@RequestBody IStorable entity) {

        try {
            
            daoServiceImpl.persistEntity(entity);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED, e.getMessage());
        }

        return new ResponseEntity("Object updated successfully", HttpStatus.CREATED);

    }
}
```

And my service:

```
package com.project.biddingSoft.service;
public class DaoServiceImpl {

    @Autowired
    private IRepo iRepo; 
    
    public  boolean persistEntity(IStorable entity ) throws IllegalArgumentException {
         
        try {
            IStorable success = iRepo.save(entity);
        }
        catch(IllegalArgumentException e) {
            logger.info("Error is " ,e);
            throw e; 
        }
        return true; 
        
    }
}
```

This is the error I'm getting:

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
12:04:51.237 [restartedMain] ERROR o.s.boot.SpringApplication - Application run failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'servletInitializer': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'daoServiceImpl'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'daoServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'iRepo'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'IRepo' defined in com.project.biddingSoft.dao.IRepo defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on BiddingSoftwareApplication: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: interface com.project.biddingSoft.model.IStorable
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:660)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:640)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:119)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1413)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:601)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:944)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:917)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:582)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:144)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:767)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:426)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:326)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1311)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1300)
    at com.project.biddingSoft.BiddingSoftwareApplication.main(BiddingSoftwareApplication.java:29)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'daoServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'iRepo'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'IRepo' defined in com.project.biddingSoft.dao.IRepo defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on BiddingSoftwareApplication: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: interface com.project.biddingSoft.model.IStorable
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:660)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:640)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:119)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1413)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:601)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1380)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1300)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:657)
    ... 26 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'IRepo' defined in com.project.biddingSoft.dao.IRepo defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on BiddingSoftwareApplication: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: interface com.project.biddingSoft.model.IStorable
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1786)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:602)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1380)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1300)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:657)
    ... 40 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: interface com.project.biddingSoft.model.IStorable
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.MetamodelImpl.managedType(MetamodelImpl.java:582)
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.MetamodelImpl.managedType(MetamodelImpl.java:85)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.<init>(JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.java:75)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaEntityInformationSupport.getEntityInformation(JpaEntityInformationSupport.java:66)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getEntityInformation(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:229)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:179)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:162)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:72)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:281)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.lambda$afterPropertiesSet$5(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:323)
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.getNullable(Lazy.java:230)
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.get(Lazy.java:114)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:329)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:144)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1845)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1782)
    ... 50 common frames omitted
```

**Edit:**

I tried changing IStorable to Storable and make my entity classess extend this instead of IStorable:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public  class Storable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    protected  Long id;
    
    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }
}
```

But now I'm getting the following error when issuing my post request in postman:

```
 "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "trace": "org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Unknown entity: com.project.biddingSoft.domain.Storable; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown entity: com.project.biddingSoft.domain.Storable\r\n\tat org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils.convertJpaAccessExceptionIfPossible(EntityManagerFactoryUtils.java:374)\r\n\tat org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:235)\r\n\tat org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:551)\r\n\tat org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:61)\r\n\tat org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:242)\r\n\tat org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:152)\r\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)\r\n\tat org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:174)\r\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)\r\n\tat org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97)\r\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)\r\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215)\r\n\tat com.sun.proxy.$Proxy94.save(Unknown Source)\r\n\tat com.project.biddingSoft.service.DaoServiceImpl.persistEntity(DaoServiceImpl.java:36)\r\n\tat com.project.biddingSoft.controller.ServletInitializer.addNewEntity(ServletInitializer.java:77)\r\n\tat java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)\r\n\tat java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64)\r\n\tat java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)\r\n\tat java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:197)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:141)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:106)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:894)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1060)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:962)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909)\r\n\tat javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:652)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)\r\n\tat javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:346)\r\n\tat org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:374)\r\n\tat org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)\r\n\tat org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:887)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1684)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)\r\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)\r\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)\r\n\tat java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)\r\nCaused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown entity: com.project.biddingSoft.domain.Storable\r\n\tat org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:723)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:706)\r\n\tat java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)\r\n\tat java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64)\r\n\tat java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)\r\n\tat java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)\r\n\tat org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:362)\r\n\tat com.sun.proxy.$Proxy91.persist(Unknown Source)\r\n\tat java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)\r\n\tat java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64)\r\n\tat java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)\r\n\tat java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)\r\n\tat org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:311)\r\n\tat com.sun.proxy.$Proxy91.persist(Unknown Source)\r\n\tat org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.save(SimpleJpaRepository.java:557)\r\n\tat java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)\r\n\tat java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64)\r\n\tat java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)\r\n\tat java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)\r\n\tat org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker$RepositoryFragmentMethodInvoker.lambda$new$0(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:289)\r\n\tat org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.doInvoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:137)\r\n\tat org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.invoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:121)\r\n\tat org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$RepositoryFragments.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:524)\r\n\tat org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:285)\r\n\tat org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:531)\r\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)\r\n\tat org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:156)\r\n\tat org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:131)\r\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)\r\n\tat org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123)\r\n\tat org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:388)\r\n\tat org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119)\r\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)\r\n\tat org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137)\r\n\t... 59 more\r\n",
    "message": "Unknown entity: com.project.biddingSoft.domain.Storable; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown entity: com.project.biddingSoft.domain.Storable",
    "path": "/addent"
```

How can I, without changing how to CrudeRepository is parameterized, allow for all my attributes of the sub-class to be persisted? That is, for the program to ignore the Storable super class and straight away look what's underneath it?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use an interface with `CrudRepository` because the interface itself does not quarantee it's every implementation is going to be an `@Entity` (a managed type). You have to use specific implementation that is an `@Entity` instead - `CrudRepository<Lot, Long>`.

Comment: But how can I get my ServletInitializer and DaoServiceImpl to only ever have to worry about one type of object coming through and being returned via http/ResponseEntity as opposed to loads of different entities each having their own table in the database? 

Would this be best done by a super class that all entities extend or is it even possible to use an abstract class?

Comment: I looked at data rest. I can see how it saves a lot of boiler plate code but I don't see how it would this particular problem?

Answer (score 0):

I half solved my problem by delegating the CRUD operations to the entity object itself:

I have my LotRepo:

```
@Repository 
public interface ILotRepo extends  CrudRepository<Lot, Long> {
}
```

Then I have my IStorable interface:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property = "type", defaultImpl = Lot.class)
@JsonSubTypes({ @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = User.class, name = "user"),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Bid.class, name = "bid") })
public interface IStorable {

    public Long getId();

    public void setId(Long id);

    public boolean saveToRepo();

    public Iterable<? extends IStorable> findAll();

    public Optional<? extends IStorable> findById(Long id);

    public void deleteById(Long id);
}
```

Then I have my entity class:

```
@Entity
@Component
public class Lot implements IStorable {

    public Lot() {
        }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

setters, getters etc.

    @Transient
    @Autowired
    private static ILotRepo iLotRepo;

   @Autowired
    public void setILotRepo(ILotRepo ilotrepo) {
     iLotRepo = ilotrepo;
   }

    @Override
    public Optional<? extends IStorable> findById(Long id) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        Optional<Lot> lot = null;
        try {
            lot = iLotRepo.findById(id);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            throw e;
        }
        return lot;
    }
  
other CRUD operators' implementations...

}
```

And my controller:

```
@RestController
        public class ServletInitializer extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
        
            @Autowired
            private DaoServiceImpl daoServiceImpl;
       
    
     
    @GetMapping(path = "/getent/{id}")
public ResponseEntity<? extends IStorable> getEntity(@PathVariable Long id, @RequestBody IStorable entity) {
    Optional<? extends IStorable> results = daoServiceImpl.getEntityById(id, entity);
    if (results.isPresent())
        return ResponseEntity.ok(results.get());
    else
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
}
    
            @PostMapping(path = "/addent")
            ResponseEntity<Object> addNewEntity(@RequestBody IStorable entity) {
                try {
        
                    daoServiceImpl.persistEntity(entity);
                } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                    throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED, e.getMessage());
                }
                return new ResponseEntity("Object updated successfully", HttpStatus.CREATED);
        
            }
        
        Mappings for other CRUD requests
        }
```

And finally my Dao Service:

```
    @Service
    @Component
    public class DaoServiceImpl {

    public Optional<? extends IStorable> getEntityById(Long id, IStorable entity) {
        return entity.findById(id);
    }
    
    public boolean persistEntity(IStorable entity) throws IllegalArgumentException {
    
            try {
                entity.saveToRepo();
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                logger.info("Error is ", e);
                throw e;
            }
            return true;
    
        }
    
    Services for the other CRUD requests...
    }
```

So now, I can have any object coming in (eg. {"type": "user"}) and one controller and one service handling them all, without needing to know which implementation of IStorable we're dealing with. On the other hand, we delegate the responsibility of dealing with storage and how to do it - to the objects themselves.

So now I can have another repo like this:

```
@Repository
public interface IUserRepo extends  CrudRepository<User, Long> {

}
```

and give it to the User class who also implements IStorable.

Answer (score -1):

Try change this:
CrudRepository<IStorable, Long>

for that:

CrudRepository<Lot, Long>

Comment: It was like that initially but that's the whole point of my change. I may have another entity class that also implements IStorable. I don't want to have to implement the methods inside my DaoServiceImpl class, separately, for each entity object (that comes through an http requests) nor do I want a separate repo for each entity object as far as the typical , basic CRUD operations are concerned?